# Calling textViewDidBeginEditing when UITextView is Edited in Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextfield, tableview

I can't seem to get my `textViewDidBeginEditing` function to call when my textview is being edited in my ViewController.

Here's the code for my custom cell:

```
class NoteDetailCell: UITableViewCell {
    let noteText: UITextView = {
        let label = UITextView()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Nunito",size: 16)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 244, g: 244, b: 255)
        label.text = "Have to check out this food place. The best burgers in town."
        label.textColor = UIColor(r: 88, g: 88, b: 88)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .`default`, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        addSubview(noteText)

        noteText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        noteText.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        noteText.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Here's my code for my tableview:

```
class TripNoteViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {
    var noteDetails: UITableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        noteDetails.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-140)

        noteDetails.delegate = self
        noteDetails.dataSource = self
        noteDetails.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        noteDetails.register(NoteDetailCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "detailsCell")
        noteDetails.register(NoteOriginCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "visitTrip")
        noteDetails.register(NoteActionsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "noteActions")

    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(noteText: UITextView) {
        print("noteText text")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: detailsCell) as! NoteDetailCell
        cell.noteText.isScrollEnabled = false
        cell.noteText.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}
```

I would like to call the `textViewDidBeginEditing` function from my ViewController when the textfield in my custom cell is being edited. Any suggestions on what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not implemented the method defined by the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. Change:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(noteText: UITextView) {
    print("noteText text")
}
```

to:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ noteText: UITextView) {
    print("noteText text")
}
```

Since you have the wrong signature, it's not called.